# How to implement MPR Algorithm in TCP using NS2(C++)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tcp, ns2

Pseudo code for modified packet reordering (MPR)
algorithm

```
Initialization:

1) mode=slow-start
2) cwnd=1
3) memorize=0
4) alpha=0.99
5) beta=3.0
6) mxrtt=0
7) srtt=6.0
8) remove(to-be-ack , n)
9) add(to-be-sent , n)
10)if not is-in(memorize , n) then /*new drop*/
11)memorize=to-be-ack
12)cwnd = cwnd(n)/2
13)else
14)remove(memorize , n)

New ack received:

15)if (cwnd < ssthresh)
16)/* Slow Start*/
17)cwnd = cwnd + 1;
18)else
19)/* Congestion Avoidance */
20)cwnd = cwnd + 1/cwnd

Timeout:
21)/* Multiplicative decrease */
22)ssthresh = cwnd/2;
23)cwnd = 1;
```

I know that these changes must be made in the tcp.cc file in the ns2.35 folder. I am not able to follow through the initialisation part. Any guidance towards the correct implementation is welcome!